# Custom Authorize attribute with redirect to original URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, attributes, authorization

i had previously been handling roles/access rights with my own classes and if statements, in which the original URL of user was saved incase he is not even logged in, Once user logs in he is redirected to his original page. Now below is my old code. I am having difficulty to use same logic in my custom authorize attribute. please guide. Thank you

(Old method) Wrapper in every action method

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string DealType)
        {
            User user = Session["CurrentUser"] as User;
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.IsInRole(RoleType.MASTER) || user.IsInRole(RoleType.VIEW))
                {
                    // Money Shot
                    List<Deal> deals = dataBase.Deals.Where(d => d.DealType.Equals(DealType)).ToList();

                    return View(deals);
                }
                else
                {
                    return PartialView("_unauthorize");
                }
            }
            else
            {
// I need to handle this part in custom attribute
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User", new { RedirectURL= string.Format("/{0}/{1}", "Deal", "Index") });
            }
        }
```

and in my login action method i used this

```
public ActionResult Login(User model){
//Code of matching username and password...
//Validations/ exceptions handling of incorrect passwords

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RedirectURL))
                            {
                                return Redirect(RedirectURL);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                            }
}
```

Now since i learned about custom attributes i applied them like below

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeUserAttribute(params RoleType[] roleTypes)
    {
        AccessLevels = roleTypes;
    }

    // Custom property
    public RoleType[] AccessLevels { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        User user = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as User;

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.IsInRole(AccessLevels))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
//redirect URL should be save here but this is boolean method!
                return false;
            }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "User",
                            action = "Unauthorised"
                        })
                    );
    }
}
```

i used them like this

```
[AuthorizeUser(RoleType.DELETE, RoleType.ADMIN)]
```

Now issue is that if user has completely not even logged in the URL which he was accessing should be saved and once he logs in he should be redirected to where he came from. Hope i explained it well.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel here. ASP.NET already keeps track of the URL when redirecting to the login page by default. Try creating a new MVC 4/5 project and you can see how it is done.

Comment: Yes i know, but i am not using identity framework, is this URL redirecting variable available in Authorize Attribute?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            RedirectToRouteResult routeData = null;
            var returnUrl = string.Empty;

            if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
                 returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath;

            if (CurrentUser == null)
                routeData = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", returnUrl = returnUrl}));
            else
                routeData = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied"}));

            filterContext.Result = routeData;
        }
```

In the code above (inside of your custom AuthorizeAttribute) you can capture the return URL using the available request information.

This will make your returnUrl available within the Request.QueryString[] dictionary.

On your Login view you'll need to put something like this to make it actionable.

```
@{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
}
```

and then in your login form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new{@class="form-horizontal form-material", @onsubmit="return loading_event();", @id="loginForm"}))
```